# AWS Athena - Unnesting Array of Json String with blanks

Tags: json, amazon-athena

I have a string column in my Athena table that contains a JSON. One row can have multiple JSONs, and at the same time, there might be blanks (equivalent to null representations). I need to split this string into multiple rows.

**Example of my JSON string:**

```
id| Value                            | 
--| -------------------------------- | 
1 | {"col1":"abc"},{"col2":"def"}    | 
2 | {"col1":"abc"},                  |
3 | {"col1":"abc"},,{"col2":"def"}   |
```

**Expected output:**

```
id| Value                            | 
--| -------------------------------- | 
1 | {"col1":"abc"}                   | 
1 | {"col2":"def"}                   | 
2 | {"col1":"abc"}                   |
2 | null                             |
3 | {"col1":"abc"}                   |
3 | null                             |
3 | {"col2":"def"}                   |
```

ID 2 has a blank as the second JSON, and I want to translate it into a null value while unnesting. I tried the following query:

```sql
select id,s_value
from table_name, 
UNNEST(cast(json_parse('['||value||']'') as ARRAY<JSON>)) as t(s_value)
```

The above code works for ID 1 but is unable to parse the JSON for IDs 2 and 3, as it has blanks that invalidate the JSON. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this done?

Note: I tried the same approach in BigQuery, and it appears to work perfectly there, as BigQuery understands blanks as null values. However, I'm not sure what needs to be done in Athena.